# Move a file and leave a soft link behind

Tags: linux, command-line-interface, symlink

I'm looking for a single linux command that allows me to do the equivalent of this:

```
cp /some/path/file /another/path/ && ln -sf /another/path/file /some/path/
```

If there isn't one, what's the best way to do this for a bunch of files?

Comment: I don't know Bash scripting well enough to write it, but my solution  would be to just write a script and call it something catchy like cpln

Comment: Shouldn't cp be mv?

Comment: No. The -f option to ln takes care of that.

Comment: try it on a 10GB file

Comment: To be safe you should use a `;` instead of `&&`. With `&&`, there is no guarantee that `ln` won't replace the original file with a soft link before `cp` has proceeded to read the file. You should also check the return value of `cp` in order to not write the file over with `ln` if the copy fails.

Comment: @HelloGoodbye You're confusing `&&` with `&`. As written, the line does check the return value of cp and only runs the second part if it succeeded.

Comment: @itsadok AHA!!!

Comment: The best answer to this question is here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/228166/7000

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A small note, is that you could use ln both times to make the command not actually move the data (assuming both paths are on the same filesystem).

```
ln /some/path/file /another/path/ && ln -sf /another/path/file /some/path/
```

But I assume that you want to move the content of /some/path/ to an other disk, and then create links to the new files so "no one" notices.

```
for f in `ls /some/path/`; do ln /some/path/$f /another/path/ && ln -sf /another/path/$f /some/path; done
```

Wrapping it in a bash function:

```
function cpln {
    for f in `ls $1`
    do
        ln $1/$f $2 && ln -sf $2/$f $1
    done
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to make this work if what I'm moving happens to be a directory?

Comment: How does this move the actual file on disk?

Comment: Ibrahim: the data doesn't move, it just updates the pointers in the directory.

Comment: tladuke: Yes and no. Since the directory is much smaler on disk, there is no need for the ln trick (which don't work for directorys), just do a mv :-)

Answer (score 2):

Theres my script you could use (takes two parameters /some/path/file and /another/path/ ):

```
#!/bin/bash
cp $1 $2
if [ "$?" -ne "0" ]; then
    echo "Some error"
    exit 1
    fi
ln -sf $2/${1##*/} ${1%/*}
```

Comment: Cool trick with the string manipulations, never saw that before. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Seriously, I thought this was a really easy question.

Here's what I can do in perl:

```
#!/bin/perl
# Usage: cpln TARGETDIR SOURCE...
# Example: find tree/ -type f | xargs cpln commands/

$target = shift;

foreach(@ARGV) {
    m[(.*)/([^/]+)];
    system("cp $_ $target");
    system("ln -sf $target/$2 $1/");
}
```

I was hoping for something more elegant, but I guess I'll use that.

Comment: To do it "in Perl," you should use File::Copy (or similar) and symlink().  Perl is not shell; avoid system(), and *especially* avoid passing whole command lines to system() (e.g., what if an argument contains a space?).  Either way, always, always, ALWAYS check return values.